# Which file and what field I must set up My Idp Metada url with itfoxtec

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I am using itfoxtec library for a SAML2 project, but not sure where do I have to set my IPD Metadata url. I am testing with TestIdpCore and TestWebApp. Please give me a help with this.

I am expecting that when I login, the app send me to my IdP in order to enter my credentials and then take me back to my Service provider. I already have my IDP metadata url. Just need to know where to place it

Answer (score 0):

In the TestWebApp sample you can set the metadata URL in [web.config](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/test/TestWebApp/Web.config#L16) in the property `Saml2:IdPMetadata`.

In the TestWebAppCore sample you can set the metadata URL in [appsettings.json](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/test/TestWebAppCore/appsettings.json#L11) in the property `IdPMetadata`.

Comment: Hello Anders. The fact is if I set the metadata URL in the webconfig in the property Saml2:IdPMetadata, it won´t hit TestIdpCore project (https://localhost:44305/metadata) and this project returns the AssertionConsumerService location. So if I do that, my TestWebapp won't hit AssertionConsumerService method.